# Lock zIndex of a ContentPresenter Upon Mouse Enter or Drag Complete

Tags: c#, wpf, z-index, itemscontrol, .net-core-3.1

I need to lock the Z-order of a canvas/content control after it is dragged by a `Thumb`.

In the below image, the "Joe Smith" pops above the others the other two ellipses while the the mouse over is active. Once the drag stops and the mouse moves out, it drops back to its value.

I am unable to find a solution within the design I have shown below to keep it locked above the others.

[image: Joe moves in front, only to be dropped back behind Jenny.]

---

**Minimal Reproducible Example**

I have created a [code gist](https://gist.github.com/CheetahChrome/e3cf1e09b29075547ea935afc82e7c9b) of all code that contains the xaml, the thumb class and the people class. All one has to do is create a .Net Core WPF app and drop in the snippets of code and set name spacing in Xaml as needed.

---

**Design**
There is an `ItemsControl` which has `DataTemplate` defined with a `Canvas`. Each content in the `ItemsControl` has `ContentControl` which has a `Thumb` as applied by a style.

Another style trigger of the mouse entering the `ContentPresenter` has the content *temporarily* pushed in `zIndex` above the others by setting the content's internal `Grid`'s `zIndex` to 1.

How to *stick* that `zIndex`?

**Xaml**

```
<ItemsControl Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource People}}">

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Canvas>
                <ContentControl  Width="100" Height="100" >
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse Fill="Silver">
                            <Ellipse.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Direction="320"  ShadowDepth="6"  Opacity="0.5"/>
                            </Ellipse.Effect>
                        </Ellipse>
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock Margin="3,3,3,0" Text="{Binding Path=First}"/>
                            <TextBlock Margin="3,0,3,7" Text="{Binding Path=Last}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ContentControl>
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Grid.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

*See the Gist for all supporting classes and styles to reproduce*

---

**Actual Design**

The ultimate goal is to have a panel of images of a set size, when the user grabs the thumb the image it will move forward and lock above the others. I say this in-case there is another way to do that which could provide an answer above the minimal example design.

Comment: For achieving something similar, I used Canvas as ItemsPanelTemplate. To arrange the items inside the Canvas ItemsPanel, I used Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top. To make the ZIndex of last interacted item on top, I would change the Canvas.ZIndex of this clicked item on every mouse click/drag complete. Highest ZIndex was stored and incremented on every action.

Comment: @Insane I'm wondering if I have *designed* myself into a hole with this one. Your suggestion of the *tracked* canvases is one worth exploring if this doesn't pan out for me. &thx If nothing else, looking into getting the currently dragged item via that event is doable and resetting the other items in a kept list in code behind gives me pause.

Comment: @Insane I found a different work around which doesn't need to save the Highest ZIndex. Check out the answer provided if interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my `ItemsControl` I changed the `ItemsPanelTemplate` to be a `Canvas` such as

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <Canvas x:Name="MainCanvas" />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Which when looking at the Visual Tree where the user was clicking the `ContentControl`, it had a parent of a `Canvas` that had a `ContentPresenter` with that top level `Canvas` such as (*see named `MainCanvas`*):

[image: Visual tree]

I changed the `ContentControl` to have a `MouseEnter` event :

```
<ContentControl  Width="100" Height="100" MouseEnter="EnterMouse">
   <Grid>
       <Ellipse Fill="Silver">
```

In that method I needed to find the named "MainCanvas" `Canvas` and enumerate all of its children the `ContentPresenter`s and extract the max ZIndex and then set my `ContentControl` (shown in blue above) to that ZIndex value plus 1.

Here is the code behind where extract the necessary the parents:

```
private void EnterMouse(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is ContentControl cc)
    {
        var cpParent = FindParent<ContentPresenter>(cc);
        var p2 = FindParent<Canvas>(cpParent);

        var max = p2.Children.Cast<UIElement>().Max(control => Panel.GetZIndex(control));
        Panel.SetZIndex(cpParent, max + 1);
    }
}

private T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
{
    DependencyObject immediateParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

    T parent = immediateParent as T;

    return parent ?? FindParent<T>(immediateParent);
}
```